# 6x9 document class?

Tags: document-classes, dimensions

How do I explicitly define my `documentclass` to be 6x9 (i.e., typical book style)?

```
\documentclass{article}

%Russian-specific packages
%--------------------------------------
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
%--------------------------------------

%Hyphenation rules
%--------------------------------------
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\hyphenation{ма-те-ма-ти-ка вос-ста-нав-ли-вать}
%--------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\begin{abstract}
  Это вводный абзац в начале документа.
\end{abstract}

\section{Предисловие}
Текст, использующий кириллицу, чтобы показать, что символы отображаются правильно. Вы должны установить правильные кодировку и шрифт, чтобы всё работало.

\section{Математические формулы}
Кириллические символы также могут быть использованы в математическом режиме.

\begin{equation}
  S_\textup{ис} = S_{123}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I tried using the advice here: [How to make document custom page dimensions?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80505/how-to-make-document-custom-page-dimensions), but my page came out looking a little strange.  Perhaps there is a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6in, paperheight=9in, margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```