# Best strategy for setting page format for a book

Tags: layout

I want to write a book, the format of which is 7 X 10 (in).

What are the different strategies to set this format? I mean: which package (embedded? geometry? other?), and what do I have to care about during this process?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: This is way too broad a question as there are many things too consider. Perhaps consider read this: [Strategy for writing a book using LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/302222/5764)

Comment: I read this topic but it doesn't answer my question. If start my document with "\documentclass[a4paper", I'm wrong...! So my question remains: how to achieve my goal?

Comment: The thing is, "best" is a relative term that may be different for different people. The US/Canada uses letter size, while the UK uses A-style paper sizes. That's just for the paper size... I'm sure there are other options when talking about the other document elements.

Comment: Whaoo! Hard... OK, I've changed the text. Hope it is less "relative"... So I resume: how to set a 7x10 po page?

Comment: Is *po* a non-english designation for *inches*? So basically your question is how to fix the page to be 7x10 inches? Then you might be interested in [How to make document custom page dimensions?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/80505/82917)

Comment: Right, po=in, sorry for this mistake, I'm going to edit. Thanks for the answer. It seems to work, and I have to manage with the inner margins... Are there other ways to set the page format? Or is this (simple) one is the one generally used?

Comment: `geometry` is the normal answer for the standard classes. The KoMa classes (and maybe `memoir`) have their own ways of setting the page size and margins.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the `memoir` class (a superset of `book`, `report`, and `article`) which provides 7 different page layouts. It, of course, enables you to specify your own page layout in a slightly different method than the `geometry` package.

You might find my *A Few Notes on Book Design* (`> texdoc memdesign`) helpful regarding page layout and general considerations when typesetting a book.

Comment: +1 Because I’ve found these resources very useful for the formation of a book. Given the generality of the question I believe this is a good answer

Comment: Thanks for this reference. It's interesting but it requires a deep investment (PDF memoir class is more than 600 pages...). I'll have a more detailed look if I can't reach my goal with the advice given upper.

Comment: @AlexAndre But did you look at `memdesign` which discusses book layout while `memoir` helps you do the layout?