# Custom page dimensions (60×90/16)

Tags: paper-size

In Ukraine, formats such as 60×90/16, 60×84/16, 84×108/32 and so on are accepted for printing books.

How do I specify such a custom format in LaTeX?

Comment: Have you seen this answer? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80505/how-to-make-document-custom-page-dimensions

Comment: If you are looking for multipage formats (the folios for cutting and folding) I think that the composition is made by the printer starting from the "normal" PDF. There is a package (https://ctan.org/pkg/booklet?lang=en) doing a similar thing, but it's thought for home-made things...